# Whole ALAssetsLibrary upload

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I've got the following big issue. I'm writing an app, that **syncs** all media library with remote server ( like dropbox Sync API does ). 
So, it's quite a complicated deal, so I've got camera roll with 800+ photos and dozens of albums with lots of photos - it's quite a hard task for memory.

I don't think, there are any **3-rd party solutions for that**, so **what can you advise me to start with**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/pavelosipov/POSInputStreamLibrary) is my pod which I wrote for the same use case. It is not a whole solution, but just a building block.

Comment: Спасибо, похоже на необходимое решение. Осталось вписать в нашу архитектуру

Comment: Единственно, я не пробовал, как оно ведет себя в фоне. Есть подозрение, что у тасок NSURLSession нет доступа к ALAssetLibrary на залоченном телефоне.

Comment: В продолжение обсуждения решения - если не секрет, сколько времени Ваша команда разрабатывала это решение и в каком составе? Заранее благодарю!